# Missing Bundle-ManifestVersion for Vaadin-CDI

Tags: vaadin, apache-karaf

I'm trying to use Vaadin-CDI 11.0.0.rc1 with Karaf 4.2.5 . When trying to install the bundle directly, it throws me an error :

```
Bundle IDs: 
Error executing command: Error installing bundles:
    Unable to install bundle mvn:com.vaadin/vaadin-cdi/11.0.0.rc1:
    org.osgi.framework.BundleException: OSGi R3 bundle not supported
```

And when I try installing it from a feature.xml inside my-project I get a different error :

```
karaf@root()> feature:install com.my-project.feature
org.apache.karaf.features.internal.util.MultiException: Error:
    Unable to create resource for bundle mvn:com.vaadin/vaadin-cdi/11.0.0.rc1
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.MavenDownloadManager$MavenDownloader.<init>(MavenDownloadManager.java:91)
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.MavenDownloadManager.createDownloader(MavenDownloadManager.java:72)
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.Subsystem.downloadBundles(Subsystem.java:457)
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.Subsystem.downloadBundles(Subsystem.java:452)
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.SubsystemResolver.resolve(SubsystemResolver.java:224)
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:388)
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.doProvision(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1058)
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.lambda$doProvisionInThread$13(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:994)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: Unable to create resource for bundle mvn:com.vaadin/vaadin-cdi/11.0.0.rc1
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.Subsystem.createResource(Subsystem.java:824)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.Subsystem.lambda$downloadBundles$1(Subsystem.java:499)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.MavenDownloadManager$MavenDownloader.lambda$download$0(MavenDownloadManager.java:138)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.DefaultFuture.notifyListener(DefaultFuture.java:350)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.DefaultFuture.notifyListeners(DefaultFuture.java:335)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.DefaultFuture.setValue(DefaultFuture.java:259)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.AbstractDownloadTask.setFile(AbstractDownloadTask.java:61)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.AbstractRetryableDownloadTask.run(AbstractRetryableDownloadTask.java:61)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
        ... 3 more
    Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to build resource for mvn:com.vaadin/vaadin-cdi/11.0.0.rc1: Unsupported 'Bundle-ManifestVersion' value: 1
        at org.apache.felix.utils.resource.ResourceBuilder.build(ResourceBuilder.java:82)
        at org.apache.felix.utils.resource.ResourceBuilder.build(ResourceBuilder.java:71)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.Subsystem.createResource(Subsystem.java:822)
        ... 13 more
    Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unsupported 'Bundle-ManifestVersion' value: 1
        at org.apache.felix.utils.resource.ResourceBuilder.doBuild(ResourceBuilder.java:90)
        at org.apache.felix.utils.resource.ResourceBuilder.build(ResourceBuilder.java:80)
        ... 15 more
Error executing command: Error:
    Unable to create resource for bundle mvn:com.vaadin/vaadin-cdi/11.0.0.rc1
```

So I headed to the MANIFEST.MF of Vaadin-CDI and discovered that there is no Bundle-ManifestVersion inside it.
Is it normal ? If not, how do I fix it ?

**EDIT :**

I tried cloning vaadin-cdi in my project and then I replaced VaadinServlet with CdiVaadinServlet, the build goes smoothly, and when I install it in Karaf there's no problem until I go in the logs in which I see there's a NullPointerException :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.project.pax.vaadin.cdi.BeanLookup.lookupOrElseGet(BeanLookup.java:87) ~[49:com.project.pax.vaadin:0.1.0.SNAPSHOT]
    at com.project.pax.vaadin.cdi.BeanLookup.lookup(BeanLookup.java:105) ~[49:com.project.pax.vaadin:0.1.0.SNAPSHOT]
    at com.project.pax.vaadin.cdi.CdiVaadinServletService.lookup(CdiVaadinServletService.java:170) ~[49:com.project.pax.vaadin:0.1.0.SNAPSHOT]
    at com.project.pax.vaadin.cdi.CdiVaadinServletService.init(CdiVaadinServletService.java:123) ~[49:com.project.pax.vaadin:0.1.0.SNAPSHOT]
    at com.project.pax.vaadin.cdi.CdiVaadinServlet.createServletService(CdiVaadinServlet.java:91) ~[49:com.project.pax.vaadin:0.1.0.SNAPSHOT]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.createServletService(VaadinServlet.java:186) ~[65:com.vaadin.flow.server:2.0.0.rc2]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.init(VaadinServlet.java:73) ~[65:com.vaadin.flow.server:2.0.0.rc2]
    at com.project.pax.vaadin.cdi.CdiVaadinServlet.init(CdiVaadinServlet.java:54) ~[49:com.project.pax.vaadin:0.1.0.SNAPSHOT]
    at com.project.pax.vaadin.osgi.VaadinServletRegistration$FixedVaadinServlet.init(VaadinServletRegistration.java:31) ~[49:com.project.pax.vaadin:0.1.0.SNAPSHOT]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:670) ~[119:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:9.4.12.v20180830]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:427) ~[119:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:9.4.12.v20180830]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:760) ~[119:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:9.4.12.v20180830]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:374) ~[119:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:9.4.12.v20180830]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.startContext(HttpServiceContext.java:414) ~[145:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:7.2.8]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:847) ~[118:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.4.12.v20180830]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:287) ~[119:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:9.4.12.v20180830]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.doStart(HttpServiceContext.java:267) ~[145:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:7.2.8]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) ~[121:org.eclipse.jetty.util:9.4.12.v20180830]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerImpl$1.start(JettyServerImpl.java:329) ~[145:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:7.2.8]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.HttpServiceStarted.registerServlet(HttpServiceStarted.java:252) ~[?:?]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.HttpServiceStarted.registerServlet(HttpServiceStarted.java:392) ~[?:?]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.HttpServiceProxy.registerServlet(HttpServiceProxy.java:504) ~[?:?]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.whiteboard.internal.element.ServletWebElement.register(ServletWebElement.java:102) ~[?:?]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.whiteboard.internal.WebApplication.registerWebElement(WebApplication.java:392) ~[?:?]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.whiteboard.internal.WebApplication.registerWebElements(WebApplication.java:371) ~[?:?]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.whiteboard.internal.WebApplication.registerHttpContext(WebApplication.java:283) ~[?:?]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.whiteboard.internal.WebApplication.serviceChanged(WebApplication.java:232) ~[?:?]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.whiteboard.internal.WebApplication.serviceChanged(WebApplication.java:68) ~[?:?]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.whiteboard.internal.util.tracker.ReplaceableService.bind(ReplaceableService.java:86) ~[?:?]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.whiteboard.internal.util.tracker.ReplaceableService$Customizer.addingService(ReplaceableService.java:105) ~[?:?]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:941) ~[?:?]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:870) ~[?:?]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256) ~[?:?]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:229) ~[?:?]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.serviceChanged(ServiceTracker.java:901) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.invokeServiceListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:990) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:838) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.fireServiceEvent(EventDispatcher.java:545) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireServiceEvent(Felix.java:4595) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.registerService(Felix.java:3587) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:348) ~[?:?]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.Activator.updateController(Activator.java:426) ~[?:?]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.Activator.lambda$scheduleUpdateFactory$1(Activator.java:344) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
15:16:57.159 ERROR [paxweb-config-1-thread-1] Could not start the servlet context for context path []
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.ops4j.pax.web.service.spi.model.ServletModel-2@378be0fa==com.project.pax.vaadin.osgi.VaadinServletRegistration$FixedVaadinServlet,jsp=null,order=-1,inst=false
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:691) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:427) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:760) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:374) ~[?:?]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.startContext(HttpServiceContext.java:414) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:847) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:287) ~[?:?]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.doStart(HttpServiceContext.java:267) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) ~[?:?]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerImpl$1.start(JettyServerImpl.java:329) ~[?:?]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.HttpServiceStarted.registerServlet(HttpServiceStarted.java:252) ~[?:?]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.HttpServiceStarted.registerServlet(HttpServiceStarted.java:392) ~[?:?]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.HttpServiceProxy.registerServlet(HttpServiceProxy.java:504) ~[?:?]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.whiteboard.internal.element.ServletWebElement.register(ServletWebElement.java:102) ~[?:?]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.whiteboard.internal.WebApplication.registerWebElement(WebApplication.java:392) ~[?:?]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.whiteboard.internal.WebApplication.registerWebElements(WebApplication.java:371) ~[?:?]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.whiteboard.internal.WebApplication.registerHttpContext(WebApplication.java:283) ~[?:?]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.whiteboard.internal.WebApplication.serviceChanged(WebApplication.java:232) ~[?:?]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.whiteboard.internal.WebApplication.serviceChanged(WebApplication.java:68) ~[?:?]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.whiteboard.internal.util.tracker.ReplaceableService.bind(ReplaceableService.java:86) ~[?:?]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.whiteboard.internal.util.tracker.ReplaceableService$Customizer.addingService(ReplaceableService.java:105) ~[?:?]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:941) ~[?:?]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:870) ~[?:?]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256) ~[?:?]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:229) ~[?:?]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.serviceChanged(ServiceTracker.java:901) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.invokeServiceListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:990) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:838) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.fireServiceEvent(EventDispatcher.java:545) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireServiceEvent(Felix.java:4595) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.registerService(Felix.java:3587) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:348) ~[?:?]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.Activator.updateController(Activator.java:426) ~[?:?]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.Activator.lambda$scheduleUpdateFactory$1(Activator.java:344) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.project.pax.vaadin.cdi.BeanLookup.lookupOrElseGet(BeanLookup.java:87) ~[?:?]
    at com.project.pax.vaadin.cdi.BeanLookup.lookup(BeanLookup.java:105) ~[?:?]
    at com.project.pax.vaadin.cdi.CdiVaadinServletService.lookup(CdiVaadinServletService.java:170) ~[?:?]
    at com.project.pax.vaadin.cdi.CdiVaadinServletService.init(CdiVaadinServletService.java:123) ~[?:?]
    at com.project.pax.vaadin.cdi.CdiVaadinServlet.createServletService(CdiVaadinServlet.java:91) ~[?:?]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.createServletService(VaadinServlet.java:186) ~[?:?]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.init(VaadinServlet.java:73) ~[?:?]
    at com.project.pax.vaadin.cdi.CdiVaadinServlet.init(CdiVaadinServlet.java:54) ~[?:?]
    at com.project.pax.vaadin.osgi.VaadinServletRegistration$FixedVaadinServlet.init(VaadinServletRegistration.java:31) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:670) ~[?:?]
    ... 38 more
```

It seems to be related to the context-path but I'm not sure what file I should modify or add to handle that.